# Unreal Engine 4 show external login UI not working

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, unreal-engine4

The external login ui is not working for me on android. I have tried and searched for a answer but it is still not working.

This is what I have so far:
[image: external login ui not working]

Comment: Have you tried sorting some related questions in [Unreal Engine site](https://answers.unrealengine.com/index.html)?

Comment: yes, it still did work

Comment: sorry meant to say: yes, it still did not work